# What installed "DU quick charge" on my phone?

Tags: lock-screens, malware

I started seeing something new on my lock screen, before even swiping the lock screen. It was a large battery charging-status display with advertisements below that. At the upper left corner was a gear for setup. Touching that displayed "DU Quick Charge" with a little slider to turn it off. I turned it off and the display has never appeared again. But I want to know where this came from. A Google search gave me one article describing my issue exactly, except it involves different software than I have. The image provided is the same. Obviously "DU quick charge" is a library someone is selling. How do I find what software did this on my phone? It seems to have already disappeared from the recently updated list at the play store.

[Link to article](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/4g8hbq/psa_amber_weather_widget_223_adds_du_quick_charge/)

[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLMvT.jpg)

Comment: See if this is the cause: [What is this lock screen with ads and how do I remove it?](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/143373)

Comment: I voted to close as dupe of above question. There's nothing wrong with your question, but since the given answer also tries to cover your question, it's better to centralized all info, and your question is a good signpost to it.

Comment: Yes, the previous question is the same having good answers. Thanks