# Weird display on screen before swipe lock Samsung Galaxy s6 edge plus

Tags: samsung, screen

Pressed the onscreen button on my s6 edge this afternoon and a strange new display swipe screen is showing up - picture included. I have no idea where this came from and I have to swipe it just to get to my pin lock. I've checked my apps, my settings, my locked screen, I've disabled some of the apps I thought it could've been but to no avail. Does this look familiar to anyone, and if so how do I get rid of it? It's eating up my battery life.

[image: New screenlock appeared]

Comment: It's an app surely. Are you using any cleaning apps like DU speed booster? If yes tweak the settings for the same app.

Comment: Check [What is this lock screen with ads and how do I remove it?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/143330/what-is-this-lock-screen-with-ads-and-how-do-i-remove-it/143373#143373) and [Determine which app is drawing on top of other apps?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127769/determine-which-app-is-drawing-on-top-of-other-apps?lq=1)

Comment: Related [What is this lock screen with ads and how do I remove it?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/143330/131553)

Answer (score 2):

Looking around, [this reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/galaxynote5/comments/45ahkp/wtf_the_ads_showing_on_the_charging_lock_screen/d383n9n) pointed me in the right direction.
Using ES Task Manager I found all apps with a name containing "photo", and all were recently updated.

[image: ES Task Manager]

Photo Collage Editor was the culprit.

[image: Photo Collage Editor - app]
[image: Photo Collage Editor - Settings]

So if you don't like random ads forced on you, don't install this app:

[image: Photo Collage Editor - Google Play page]

I'm sure there's plenty of other apps that do collages, and are made by slightly more polite people.. I'm sure I'll find out when I need to make a collage again, but I'm not using this app ever again.

**EDIT**
This app, by the same developer ("Zentertain"), is doing the same thing:

[image: Photo Editor Pro - Google Play page]

Comment: Ouch. I'd say that's even pretty much dishonest of the dev: "Turn it on for faster charging speed". As if a photo collage app on the lock screen would have such an effect. I'd go that far to say I'd blacklist that dev altogether (never using any app that dev makes).

Comment: Yeah, fast charging is a hardware thing, so yeah, they're blatantly lying... The blacklisting thing is interesting, I might do that. Thanks!

Comment: A dev who's lying that way in one place IMHO isn't to be trusted in any other way. Just the opposite, I'd expect him to cheat in other regards as well. You could even report him to Google, as that kind of advertisement is definitely violating Playstore rules: Ads are only permitted within the app – and specifically it's **not** permitted to place it in other apps (the lockscreen is another app). Arguing this being a "lockscreen widget" is misleading, as the widget in no way states the app it belongs to. The only thing it's "charging" is the dev's account, while discharging the battery faster.

Comment: Lol @ your last sentence. Yeah, I just finished reporting the app. Boy, that takes a lot of effort. I read through [Monetization and Ads guidelines](https://play.google.com/about/monetization.html#ads-policy), and it was doing all of the things on there wrong... Don't know if me reporting him is gonna do anything though.

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me and it was an ab workout app. My advice would be to try to delete the most recent app you downloaded before you noticed it. From the looks of it, multiple apps do this.

Answer (score -2):

It was picsart doing this to my device. Removed app and it's gone. It was annoying.

Comment: Please link the app from play store