# Remove lockscreen app via adb

Tags: adb

A relative installed a bunch of apps, and now I am infected by some app with a pesky ad-filled lockscreen, ON TOP of the regular lockscreen (why are they even allowed to do that).

How can I find the name of the current lockscreen app using adb so I could remove it?

Using `adb shell dumpsys activity | grep mFocus` yielded `com.android.settings` which I presume is the stock lockscreen.

I dont want to format the device nor delete a bunch of apps until I uninstall the right one.

Comment: Follow http://android.stackexchange.com/q/143330/96277

Comment: @Firelord thanks! I don't have any of the apps on the list though.

Comment: On that lockscreen, do you get to use Overview button? If yes, you may be able to see the name of the app in the app window when you press that button.