# Ads appearing on my lock screen, cannot identify the culprit app

Tags: lock-screens, ads

This little treat appeared on my lock screen this morning. It seems to be intermittent, only replacing the real lock screen about one in three times. Has anyone else seen it?

[image]

Comment: See if the answers here help you out: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/143330/96277

Comment: Yeah read that, didn't help me. Don't have any of those apps

Answer (score 0):

It is probably and App launcher or user installed file manager. If you use something like ES explorer, buying pro version will probably fix it. Check if the ads go away by disabling any "feature" app.

Comment: I've checked the all the lists of apps which do this but I don't have any of them. Also checked the for instances of ChargeLockerService permission, did not see it for anything

Comment: Do you have developer options enabled? If you don't, go to Settings>About Phone>Software Info>Build Number and tap build number seven times. You should have access to Developer options. Check Running Services and select apps to check the service they are running. The ones running ChargerLockerService are the culprit. 

Source: https://www.slashgear.com/android-ads-on-your-lockscreen-and-how-to-destroy-them-05438921/

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. lemme guess.. you have a Samsung device. Right?
It's not an app.. **IT'S SAMSUNG!!**

Go to settings --> Advanced --> Quick Charging and then turn it off or something..

Hope it helps!