# Android 7 Nougat onwards: hides USB OTG sticks from third-party file managers?

Tags: usb, file-management, usb-on-the-go, files

Third party file managers such as ES File Manager and RhythmSoft File Manager HD (others will be tested) do not show an USB OTG device.

It does not even get listed.
Only Android's pre-installed file manager does.

#### Is USB OTG deliberately hidden in Android ≥7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained here [How app can access files on USB OTG storages in Android 6.0 (API level 23) without root?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33626495), the accepted answer says about the change introduced from Marshamllow

> In Android 6.0, any device that is not adopted is considered portable. […] Third-party apps must go through the Storage Access Framework to interact with files on portable storage; **direct access is explicitly blocked for privacy and security reasons.**

(Emphasis added)

Which means that the File explorer needs to use Storage Access Framework (requires root as indicated in the question on SO). This XDA post [Files by Google adds support for browsing files on USB OTG drives](https://www.xda-developers.com/files-by-google-browsing-files-usb-otg-drives/) says [Files by Google](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.nbu.files) has been updated with this capability (not tested by me).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually, I still have read-only access in Android 6.0. But what bothers me is that Google ***enforces*** the default file manager instead of giving the user a consentful choice possibility. ***(Spoiler: Even the earliest versions of ES File Manager, 2010 or so, were more functional than the newest Android's built-in file manager.)*** For a long time, Android did not even have a file manager. That's right. On a Google Nexus 7, 2012, one needed separate apps to access files and also the front camera (the Nexus had no rear camera due to toxic minimalism)

Comment: Glad it helped you :). But yes ES was very good before it started carrying *dirty* payload !

Comment: *Dirty payload*? What's that? Android 4.4.2's MicroSD scandal?

Comment: See how many times ES is mentioned here [What is this lock screen with ads and how do I remove it?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/143330). I read that they have improved but I am not taking chances

Comment: I must be using an older (apparently better) version of ES.

Comment: MiXplorer by Hootan Parsa is a very appreciable replacement to ES and Solid explorers.

Comment: Can you clarify?  Your answer seems to say that using *Storage Access Framework* requires root "as indicated in the question on SO" but I read the question as saying you need root to access USB storage *directly* while the answer says you need *Storage Access Framework* but nothing about needing root.

Comment: Please try the explorer linked. I am unable to reply in detail. If that doesn't help, ping a moderator to reopen question

Comment: I also forgot to mention that all third-party apps from the past and also current ones such as VLC Media Player are now blocked from accessing OTG. That's like disabling the entire Internet access altogether, you know, _for security reasons_.