# How do I remove this odd field sometimes appearing when typing?

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, motorola-moto-g, gboard

I have recently started seeing an extra field middle left on the screen on my Android 5.1 Moto G 1st generation:

[image: winsomely]

I cannot tap it. It also appears in other apps, for instance Hangouts. I first thought it was some sort of word suggestion, but it doesn't seem to change much or always appear.

Does anybody know what that is and how to remove it?

Oh, and what does "winsomely" mean..? Thank you.

Comment: I have a hunch that it is an overlay from an app. See if this helps in tracing the app responsible for it: http://android.stackexchange.com/a/127862/96277

Comment: First of all, thank you, very interesting even if I didn't crack it yet. I tried comparing the window/package list with the box present and without (it disappears if the phone goes to sleep and you unlock the screen. I see no difference in the window list, but I can at least start on those 15 things on the list, it is obvious which programs some of them belong to even without the first list.

Answer (score -1):

It's not an extra field.  It's a malicious app that is causing it.  Download.[StopBadApp Moble Security](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.secore.privacyshield) from playstore and scan the phone to detect and remove the malicious application.

Comment: Hi, wherein lies tue malice of that malicious app, what is its purpose?

Comment: If it's a Spyware, it can be used to monitor your phone activity, capture your password or credit card transactions and send the details to a hacker or fraudulent website. Many more harm than good can be done too. [Learn more.](https://www.wou.edu/ucs/faq/spyad.php)

Comment: Do you have any reference that it's caused by malicious app?