# How to turn off the "Screen Overlay" setting?

Tags: oneplus-two

I'm using the Oneplus 2 and last week I updated my phone's software and ever since then I'm not able to do much on my phone. I'm not able to download photos on WhatsApp and neither am I able to send someone photos. Only one message keeps on popping up saying "screen overlay detected go to "App Settings" and turn it off". I tried following the instructions and turned it all off, but it was of least help. If anyone here has any clues about it, please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine which app is drawing on top of other apps?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127769/determine-which-app-is-drawing-on-top-of-other-apps)

Comment: There are three places apps are listed you have to turn off:
http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/154274/screen-overlay-detected-dialog-turned-off-everything-doesnt-work/157029#157029

Answer (score 3):

**Got insights from multiple answers here and other forums .**

**Consolidating how I got rid of the issue :**

1. Go to Settings > Apps > (your app which is getting issue)
2. Press on Power button till window for Power off , reboot , airplane mode comes up
3. Hold on Power off option
4. Select reboot in Safe mode
5. Go to settings > apps > (your app which is getting issue)
6. Select whichever permissions you want
7. After Android M update , issues can come up in apps like Messenger , Whatsapp , Prisma etc.

Let me know if any issues . 
Note : I am having One plus One mobile.

Comment: it would add to credibility if you link the sources from which you have gathered

Comment: Some different answers on forum.xda-developers.com , also few on this very page . After trying various options , I have added the steps here  that got my work done .

Comment: @beeshyams and [the answer Laila gave a few days earlier](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/152518/16575), maybe ;)

Answer (score 1):

1.Go to settings -> apps -> Click the cog gear -> Draw over other apps.

2.Proceed to disable for all the apps. Force stop the running apps.

3.Then try using whatsapp.

3a.Give permission if required by whatsapp or any other app

Most known culprits are file manager apps or screen brightness apps.

You can either disable for all apps or can go one by one.

Answer (score 1):

follow the steps:

1. press <kbd>power</kbd> button for a few seconds
2. press and hold *power off*
3. reboot to safe mode
4. let phone reboot
5. go to *Settings › Apps*
6. click on setting symbol
7. click on access permission
8. enable all the options according to your need
9. reboot your phone.

It's work for me..  :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem lies in total Android OS, when u get a heads up notification do some stuffs like this, it will ask you for this permission. The solution is: Wait for heads up to off and then try again. There is also another problem in Android for safety Google has disabled positive buttons when a screen filter is applied, check for any screen filter app or check Oneplus defaults screen filter. These are only two problems you could face for screen overlay detected.

Answer (score 0):

there is a solution for this issue. I had to face the same after my latest update.  1) delete apps like(cleanmaster, battery saver, etc.) or go to settings/app/cleanmaster/force stop. Or you can also off the permissions for cleanmaster.. Thankyou ;)

Comment: OP nowhere indicated using CleanMaster. And "delete apps like X" is a very strange recommendation – especially with the relation being unclear.