# How do I disable the "Screen overlay detected" security bandaid?

Tags: security, permissions, overlay

I use [Toucher Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gau.go.toucherpro) (whose whole point is to always be on top) essentially in place of a homescreen, insofar as I launch apps from it 95% of the time instead of using a launcher. Now, thanks to the recent security update which doesn't let you change permissions while an overlay is running, I have to disable Toucher, change the permission, and re-enable Toucher immediately because I can't use my phone without it.

This is most ridiculous when installing a new Marshmallow app, since this includes initial permission requests even for basic behavior:

[image]
[image]

I'm an advanced user, and I can smell when a malicious app is trying to fool me, so I feel reasonably safe disabling this. **Is there any way to disable this kludge?**

Comment: Have you seen [Determine which app is drawing on top of other apps?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/127769/16575) That should help you finding the culprit.

Comment: @Izzy please read my question.

Comment: I did – but reading it again, I've misread it the first time. You want to have the screen overlay ignored it seems – not much luck with that, I'm afraid, for reasons already pointed out. Sorry.

Comment: @Izzy I figured. Might there be a solution that involves rooting andor writing an app?

Comment: Would be off-topic here (development focused), but of course by altering the code one could do that. Maybe someone wrote a corresponding XPosed module for this – but there's no hit in the [XPosed repo](http://repo.xposed.info/) yet.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147228/discussion-on-question-by-ky-how-do-i-disable-the-screen-overlay-detected-se); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bandaid seems to have been removed in Nougat. So... I suppose the answer is to upgrade to Nougat?

Comment: so... no way for a Marshmallow?

Comment: @Ooker I haven't found a way. If you do, make sure to add that as an answer!

Comment: That's sad. I've thought that Xposed will free us from any limitation. So, in Nougat, the screen overlay detection just disappears? You won't need to worry about it anymore?