# Screen overlay detected app permisions

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-s7

I am really stressed out with my GSamsung S7, 
Every app i have, I cant give permission to access my phone, it keeps saying to change this permission setting, you have to turn off screen overlay from settings, which i keep doing both ways, either turn them all off, or turn them all on, or doing them one by one, nothing is working.
Help, please. I am thinking about resetting the phone, but dont really want to, unless a last resort. thanks

Comment: Are you using any apps that utilize the screen overlay feature? Something like screen filters (Screen Filter, Twilight etc).

Comment: Apps like Facebook Messenger (which draws over the screen to enable chat heads) will also cause this.

Comment: I have read about this, but dont think I have.  how can i check?

Comment: should i delete messenger?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine which app is drawing on top of other apps?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127769/determine-which-app-is-drawing-on-top-of-other-apps)

Comment: I have this same issue. I've turned them all off, *including* the system apps (`More` > `Show System Apps`)

Comment: Found the problem. It's under Accessilbity, see: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/154274/screen-overlay-detected-dialog-turned-off-everything-doesnt-work/157029#157029