# Screen dims except navigation bar

Tags: screen

On my Yoga tab (B8080-F) with Android 4.4.2 all of a sudden screen got dimmed except for the navigation menu, where it remains bright as set in the display settings. If I change brightness manually, the dimmed part of the screen also changes and if I restart, the brightness is normal but shortly after the startup screen gets dimmed again, so I am suspecting an app that can make use of screen overlay to cause this. I have uninstalled FB messenger (it uses overlay notifications) but no luck. Any idea how to figure out what app is cause this annoyance?

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: Well as it often hapens, I found out solution right after posting this question. Using instructions from this post [Determine which app is drawing on top of other apps?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127769/determine-which-app-is-drawing-on-top-of-other-apps) I have identified the offending package to be com.lenovo.powercenterhd which is Lenovo Power Manager, where at some point I have apparently enabled Protection Glassess feature, which dims the main screen. After turning it off, brightness went back to normal.