# Permissions conflict with screen overlays

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, permissions, overlay

I installed Marshmallow on my Galaxy Note 4 like 2 months ago. Everything was nice and peaceful, and I was happy to be able to select custom permissions per app.

A few days ago, out of the blue, I started getting this very irritating and well known problem, where every time I want to grant an app permissions, I have to get a message that asks me to turn off screen overlays.

The most annoying part, is that it doesn't tell me what overlaying app I have to disable. I just get this generic annoying message, PLUS, there's no master switch for overlays on my Note 4! Am I gonna have to spend the next two years being unable to give any app any permissions? Every time this happens, I spend an hour digging... This is crazy and very impractical!

What are my options here? How can I get rid of this problem once and for all?

PS: My phone is rooted, so please, whatever it takes!

Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/127769/96277

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me is: turn off all Accessibility settings in the Settings of the phone. (now I feel bad for people who need them).

Also the program Twilight was another reason contributing to the problem.