# What is this Overlay Application and How can I get rid of it?

Tags: applications, overlay

Recently this "app" has shown up on my phone. Tapping it gives me access to things like the home and back button, as well as screen lock.

[image: Overlay thing]

I can't figure out what app or setting has caused this to show up recently and I'd very much like to get rid of it as it gets in the way of using other applications. There aren't any apps that I see in the settings panel that I recognize as being this kind of tool (Lux, Twilight, Lumen, "toolbar", etc).

Comment: What is the device/model that you are using?

Comment: @singhnsk Whoops, sorry. It's an Honor 6X.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine which app is drawing on top of other apps?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127769/determine-which-app-is-drawing-on-top-of-other-apps)

Comment: @Firelord Thanks for that link, unfortunately, its not helping. OS Monitor isn't showing me any applications (lit. System and Itself) which I know is wrong. From the list of overlay applications from Adv. Perm Manager, there was only one that was installed within the timeframe of when the one I want to kill showed up, but even uninstalling it didn't help. Got any other ideas?

Comment: @Draco18s please see the edited part in my answer here: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/127862/96277 It should be able solve your problem.

Comment: @Firelord Turns out it was the Smart Assistance dock from singhnsk's answer (which I tried before going through the hassle of finding/downloading/installing the Android tools).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for adding the comment. This looks like the "**Navigation Dock**" feature of Huawei's EMUI. Because these Chinese system skins will include all features that are included with an iPhone.

You will find the option to disable if you search for *navigation dock* in your settings app.

It should also be somewhere here (varies slightly per device).

*Settings > Smart Assistance > System navigation > Navigation Dock*.

Let's see how that goes.

Comment: Bingo! That's exactly what it was.