# How to disable amazon **pop up** notification

Tags: notifications, motorola, popup

[image: This is an example of the notification]

I am using the new Moto One fusion plus.

The notification only appears as a pop up and doesn't not appear in the notification bar. I have been annoyed by the notification and have even uninstalled the amazon app from my phone, yet the notification appears very frequently. (The notification is something an Amazon ad but other times it is something else but an ad)

It did not appear in the first 2 weeks of me using the new phone, but has been constantly bugging me from the past few days.

Any help in knowledge of how to disable it will be highly appreciated.

ps: the most annoying this is the loud sound and vibration the phone makes when kept on my table  when I am focusing on something else

Comment: Looks more like a message from malware trying to redirect you to a phishing site for entering your Amazon credentials. I assume you should be able to identify the app using the way described here: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127769/determine-which-app-is-drawing-on-top-of-other-apps

Comment: When this notification appears don't click on it just press recent tab button maybe it appear as any app else you can disable android service from system app as this method works for me