# Gray link pop-up on my Android device screen

Tags: screen, android-10

[image]
[image]

Why my Android device keep gray link on the screen? When it's get rotated it will show bunch of gray link, I don't know how to make it's disappear.

I just use mouse and keyboard on my Android and the issue those gray link appear. I don't have any ideas to stop it.

Comment: Could you mention the device model and Android version? Also, if this is a screen overlay, then you could try [Determine which app is drawing on top of other apps?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/127769/44325),

Comment: I use local phone with android 10. I've been checked Im not gives other apps to draw over apps.. I just using browser chrome and via, sometimes when I click a link that's grey link appear.. this issue happen since I use mouse and keyboard on my Android