# android vpn allow connection dialog

Tags: applications, screen, vpn

I sometimes use light screen manipulating apps on my galaxy s4(such as twilight app,...) and when the apps are enable,in my vpn apps,`ok` button in `vpn allow connction dialog` does not work(cannot be tapped) but `cancel` button works az usual!
I want to know what is the behind?i think this is not a bug, it is something like a rule.

Comment: Screen overlay apps cause this; this is to prevent malicious overlay from manipulate your operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **security** is the reason

This is to prevent *Tapjacking* . See bmdixon's answer here [Screen overlay detected, what is the problem?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/148260/131553) for details

So, VPN is not permitted but if you don't have a `Cancel` option to go back ( and disable the screen app, normally option for this is available in app settings) - how do you go back ? You can't, therefore, `Cancel` option is NOT greyed out