# Cannot change weather permissions on HTC One M9

Tags: permissions, htc-one, weather

I've managed to disable to location permissions to my weather app that shows on the lock screen (I do not remember what I did to create this problem).  I am using the "default" weather app.

When I go to the weather app, in settings, and chose permissions I am not allowed to change permissions. I get the following error.

```
"To change this permission, you first have to turn off screen overlay from Settings -> Apps".
```

Weather does not appear in the screen overlay settings.

I have turned off Screen overlay for everything. And I still am not able to change the permission.

Any ideas what to try next?

Comment: Related: [What does “Drawing over other apps” mean?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/154309/16575) Maybe the answers (and links) from there provide some help?

Comment: I've through much of those.  So far no luck.  Restart did nothing.  Turning off all permissions for all apps for overlay did nothing.

Comment: Interesting timing:  HTC pushed an android update to my phone and now I am able to change permissions on the weather app.  I was able to remove the permission to my contacts and add back permission to location.   The version of the Android OS is 3.41.651.21.

Comment: I don't think 3.41.651.21 is the version of the Android OS (there is no such version; that would be some Honeycomb number and thus tablet only). It's rather some HTC specific number, not sure for what (HTC Sense, maybe?) But glad to read the update solved your issue! Maybe you [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) then and mark it "accepted", so the solution becomes visible for others with the issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Izzy I would be happy to make an answer for this.  I would like to make sure I include the correct information.  How can (or what do ) I correctly identify the update I got from HTC so a user would know what to apply to fix their problem?

Comment: I'm not familiar with HTC, so I cannot tell for sure. But in *Settings › About Phone* it should also tell you the Android version. I've no idea however how the update could be "forced" if it isn't explicitely offered.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this in response to the comments above.

HTC delivered an android update to my phone and now I am able to change permissions on the weather app. I was able to remove the permission to my contacts and add back permission to location. The version of the Android OS now installed is 6.0 Marshmellow.

I do not recall which version I had prior to the update.  I do believe the update fixed the problem however.

If there is other information you would like about the software versions on my phone please ask.  I can post as comments here.