# How can I see which application is controlling the brightness?

Tags: android-10, screen-brightness

How can I see which application is controlling the brightness?

[image]

Comment: Check your apps having [SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/154316/131553) permission, typically screen filter apps or those having device admin rights

Comment: @beeshyams Thanks, doesn't the alert come from Android OS?

Comment: Nope. Some installed app. Find out which app has that permission, using any app like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.agooday.permission). I haven't used this app, it popped up first on search or use an app from [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/171579/131553) to see which app is causing that "toast"

Comment: On second thoughts, it could be OS toast too responding to restrictions caused by another app, I am not sure but the apps in the second part of the comment above would help

Comment: Googling the toast message hinting on Netflix app modifying display setting...?

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks in my case I suspect VLC to be responsible, but I'm interested in the more general case where we have no clue on which application is controlling the brightness and would like to find the application without uninstalling the applications one by one